# Xamarin forms Editor AutoSize does not work

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, editor

Im I just misunderstanding the name "AutoSize"-property on the Editor-control or does it simply not work?

I have a control like this in xaml:

```
<Editor AutoSize="TextChanges" HeightRequest="100"/>
```

It comes out fine at height 100, but when I have written a few rows it does not change size/height. The upper text is simply scrolled up.

Comment: Better to post your whole xaml file. It might depend on your other layouts.

Answer (score 9):

**Cause:**

An Editor will not `auto-size` if the `HeightRequest` property has been set.

You can refer to :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/editor#auto-sizing-an-editor

**Solution:**

You can remove the `HeightRequest` property.And the `Editor` will automatically grows when you continue typing additional rows.

```
<Editor Text="Enter text here" AutoSize="TextChanges" />
```

Answer (score 7):

In case you want AutoSize to work and at the same time to have height of 100,
you can do something like this:create a new class that inherits Editor, override method below and use a new class instead on your page

```
protected override SizeRequest OnMeasure(double widthConstraint, double heightConstraint)
{
     var sizeRequest = base.OnMeasure(widthConstraint, heightConstraint);

     return new SizeRequest(new Size(sizeRequest.Request.Width, Math.Max(100, sizeRequest.Request.Height)));
}
```